# Installing VirtualBox on Debian 12 Testing

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian

Either running `dpkg -i virtualbox-7.0_7.0.14-161095~Debian~bookworm_amd64` or `apt install virtualbox-7.0` on my Debian 12 testing, i get a dependecy issue with libvpx

```
 virtualbox-7.0 : Depends: libvpx7 (>= 1.12.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: linux-image but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

however when i have a higher version, and same for linux-image which im not sure if it is complaining about....

```
$ apt list libvpx8
Listing... Done
libvpx8/testing,now 1.13.1-2 amd64 [installed]


$ neofetch 
       _,met$$$$$gg.           
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       ---------- 
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid x86_64 
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: Dul
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 6.6.15-amd64 
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 16 mins 
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 1632 (dpkg) 
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.2.21 
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 1920x1200 
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         DE: Xfce 4.18 
 `$$b      "-.__              WM: Xfwm4 
  `Y$$                        WM Theme: Default 
   `Y$$.                      Theme: Xfce [GTK2] 
     `$$b.                    Icons: Tango [GTK2] 
       `Y$$b.                 
          `"Y$b._             

                                                      
                                                      


$ apt list linux-image-6.6.1*
Listing... Done
linux-image-6.6.13-amd64/now 6.6.13-1 amd64 [installed,local]
linux-image-6.6.15-amd64-dbg/testing 6.6.15-2 amd64
linux-image-6.6.15-amd64-unsigned/testing 6.6.15-2 amd64
linux-image-6.6.15-amd64/testing,now 6.6.15-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-6.6.15-cloud-amd64-dbg/testing 6.6.15-2 amd64
linux-image-6.6.15-cloud-amd64-unsigned/testing 6.6.15-2 amd64
linux-image-6.6.15-cloud-amd64/testing 6.6.15-2 amd64
linux-image-6.6.15-rt-amd64-dbg/testing 6.6.15-2 amd64
linux-image-6.6.15-rt-amd64-unsigned/testing 6.6.15-2 amd64
linux-image-6.6.15-rt-amd64/testing 6.6.15-2 amd64
```

running `apt --fix-broken install` just removes the broken virtualBox install.

The exact same happens if trying to install virtualBox-6.1 instead.

Comment: You're stretching reality: you don't have Debian 12 testing, you have Debian trixie (future 13) testing. Just add Debian 12 to your Debian testing to get missing packages. Or alternatively get the Debian-provided package from sid.

Comment: @A.B, thanks. can you help understand the difference?  isnt "trixie" = "12 testing" = "next stable" ?  and should i add bookworm or sid to apt sources then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Debian 12 stable and this issue has been driving me bonkers all day. In my case, it seems to be that packages associated with linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common cannot be found in the repositories. I've tried lots of things (including wget downloading linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64_6.1.76-1_amd64.deb - hoping that might contain the package - into /var/cache/apt/archives and sudo apt installing that from there) and that gets me as far as the below...

The following NEW packages will be installed:
linux-compiler-gcc-12-x86 linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64 linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common linux-kbuild-6.1

...which then fails when trying find the below package...

linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common_6.1.76-1_all.deb

...which I've searched for, but not yet found (the closest being the above mentioned linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64_6.1.76-1_amd64.deb)

I could list all the other things that I've tried, but as none of them worked, I'll spare everyone the pain! ;-)

All the best,
Briain

Update: Fixed it, see below post.

Answer (score 0):

Progress!! :-)

I found the package, so from within /var/cache/apt/archives I ran the below two commands:

sudo wget https://debian-repo.stanford.edu/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common_6.1.76-1_all.deb

sudo apt install ./linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common_6.1.76-1_all.deb

Then I tried the below...

sudo apt install virtualbox-7.0

...which seemed to work, though I did get the below failure message right at the end (and suggestions on what next to do):

vboxdrv.sh: failed:

System is running in Secure Boot mode, however your distribution
does not provide tools for automatic generation of keys needed for
modules signing. Please consider to generate and enroll them manually:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/shim-signed/mok
sudo openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -outform DER -addext "extendedKeyUsage=codeSigning" -keyout /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv -out /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
sudo mokutil --import /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
sudo reboot
```

Restart "rcvboxdrv setup" after system is rebooted

So, I followed the above steps, answering the various cert associated questions (country, state, OU, email address, etc) and when prompted, also setting a password, then when done I sudo rebooted and I was presented with a screen asking if I wanted to install the cert, so I just followed my nose and it all went okay (and it prompted for the password that I'd set in the above steps) then when done I selected the reboot option and the machine started normally (phew; it's a dual boot with Win10 and Debian, so I was slightly worried about messing up the UEFI cert and shim, but all was okay). I then the  ran sudo rcvboxdrv setup and it spat out the below messages:

sudo rcvboxdrv setup
[sudo] password for briain:
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Signing VirtualBox kernel modules.

So I then tried systemctl --type=service --state=running to see if I could spot any interesting entries, but there were no Virtualbox related entries in the list, so I decided to list all available units (sudo systemctl list-unit-files) and I could then see a couple of promising entries (and both were enabled).

vboxdrv.service   enabled
vboxweb-service.service   enabled

Anyhow, without doing anything with the above two systemd units, I instead looked and noticed that Virtualbox was now in the desktop launcher menu, then when I clicked on it, it started just up as one would expect!

I'll carry on tomorrow and update this thread if I find anything interesting, but thus far it looks promising.

Briain

PS I just checked the version (vboxmanage -v | cut -dr -f1) which reported 7.0.14, so I then successfully downloaded and installed the appropriate version of the extension pack:

wget https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.14/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-7.0.14.vbox-extpack

sudo vboxmanage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-7.0.14.vbox-extpack

All is looking well, so tomorrow I'll mount the new partition I'd created for the VMs and try installing a new VM. :-)

Comment: Why are you giving two answers?

Comment: You should merge your two (partial) answers into one really good one. (And delete the second one)

Comment: Now that I have it fixed, I plan to merge them into a more useful (and shorter) single answer, as soon as I get some time. ;-)